# returning values from TbButtonGroup in a form

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

question :
is it possible to use TbButtonGroup as a multiple select object, in a form, where the selected  value is returned (along with other form values), when the form’s submit button is **finally** selected?

I’m trying the following. It’s to a point where the buttons exist on the page with their values, but these fail to be included when the form is finally submitted (via CHtml::submitButton)

```
      <div class="span8">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
        'type' => 'primary',
        'toggle' => 'radio',
        'buttons' => array(
            array('label'=>'option 1', 'type'=>'info', 'htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'button1', 'value'=>'1')),
            array('label'=>'option 2', 'type'=>'primary' 'htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'button2', 'value'=>'2')),
            array('label'=>'option 3', 'type'=>'success', 'htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'button3', 'value'=>'3')),
        ),
    )); ?>
  </div>
```

Is this possible?
What am I missing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's easy

Just create a hidden field (or more, depending on your needs)

```
echo $form->hiddenfield($model, 'modelAttribute', array('id'=>'hiddenFieldId'));
```

And then for every button add a js function/command for an onClick event

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
        'type' => 'primary',
        'toggle' => 'radio',
        'buttons' => array(
            array('label'=>'option 1', 'type'=>'info', 'htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'button1', 'OnClick'=>'$("#hiddenFieldId").val("1");')),
            array('label'=>'option 2', 'type'=>'primary' 'htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'button2', 'OnClick'=>'$("#hiddenFieldId").val("2");')),
            array('label'=>'option 3', 'type'=>'success', 'htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'button3', 'OnClick'=>'$("#hiddenFieldId").val("3");'')),
        ),
    )); ?>
```

Hope it helps :)